# GLPK/GLPSOL - Missing Data Columns in MIP Solution

Tags: glpk

Our application, up to this point, works using *GLPSOL version 3.1*, which, when provided with a MIP problem, outputs a solution that includes the **Status (St)** and **Marginal** columns.

We've had to upgrade to a newer version, and now, the same problem results in a solution file *lacking those columns*, as well as presenting these differences:

Original solution file:

```
Problem:    _jx1
Rows:       43
Columns:    27 (27 integer, 27 binary)
Non-zeros:  96
Status:     INTEGER OPTIMAL
Objective:  31 (MAXimization)
```

New solution file:

```
Problem:    _jx1
Rows:       42
Columns:    27
Non-zeros:  87
Status:     OPTIMAL
Objective:  C0 = 31 (MAXimum)
```

Additionally, the solver seems to crop out a few data rows.

The closest I've come to solving the issue is running the solver with the **--nomips** parameter, which gives me the aforementioned data columns, but yields different results.

The issue is that the solution is then fed to a parser, and having to tinker with said parser should be a last-resort option (and, in any case, the lack of data columns means we don't have all the information we need for the parsing).

So my question is twofold:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I set up the solver so I get the same results as before?

Thanks

Comment: how do you output your solution, with --output --write or --ranges?

Comment: the command line was something like this:

glpsol.exe input.mps --mps -o output.sol --max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
This is basically happening because there are no marginal values in mixed integer problems. In version 4.9 the developers changed the MIP solver and I think the new one won't automatically calculate "marginals".

2.
A common method is to calculate the optimal values for the integer variables with a MIP algorithm and then use the marginals of the same problem with the integer variables fixed to the MIP-Solution.

You can't do this just with glpsol and the command line options. You'll have to implement the functionality on your own in the code. In the GLPK Sourcecode exists the `glp_mpl_postsolve` function, which is also handling the solution of an problem for post processing the solution. You can probably implement the calculation in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks! Although I finally did implement a different parser, as our application really didn't need all those data columns.